# CNF form in Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have problems with CNF form of formula in boolean logic. I need to get it using only laws of boolean algebra.

The formula is:

$$(!a \land !b \land !c) \lor (!a \land !b \land d) \lor (b \land c \land !d) \lor (a \land c \land !d)$$

Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:
 $(!a \land !b \land !c) \lor (!a \land !b \land d) \lor (b \land c \land !d) \lor (a \land c \land !d)
\\ \Updownarrow \qquad\text{Distribute}
\\
((!a\land !b)\land(!c\lor d))\lor ((b\lor a)\land(c\land !d)) 
\\ \Updownarrow\qquad\text{DeMorgan}\\
(!(a\lor b)\land(!c\lor d))\lor ((b\lor a)\land !(!c\lor d)) 
\\ \Updownarrow\qquad\text{use }(!P\land Q)\lor(P\land !Q)\iff (!P\lor !Q)\land(P\lor Q)\\
(!(a\lor b)\lor !(!c\lor d))\land ((b\lor a)\lor (!c\lor d)) 
$

Can you take it from here?